# Deploy UrlShortner to prodction

Tags: express, nginx, redirect, url-shortener

I am trying to create a urlshortner which would redirect the user to an external url.

I am using node express + nginx to host it.

My express routing is very simple and is as below:

```
router.get('/:code', async (req, res) => {

fetch code from db
return res.redirect(longUrl)

}
```

and my nginx conf looks like:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert/ssl.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/cert/ssl.pem;
    
    server_name {server_name};
    

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
    }
}
```

This works well over http without nginx but when I introduce proxy using nginx it starts to redirect me to `https://localhost/longUrl` rather than `https://longUrl`

I also tried https module without nginx and I got the same result.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Comment: is the "longUrl" absolute or relative? See the doc for the difference http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: the longUrl here is absolute.